# Avoid long pattern repetition in lookahead regex - how to simplify?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regex in javascript.
The aim is to strip titles from "parts" information.
Ex:

- The revenge of the wolf - Part 2. => The revenge of the wolf
- Along the road, part III. => Along the road
- Somewhere over the rainbow (part one) => Somewhere over the rainbow
- etc [part 4#] => etc

But a special case where I want to keep the ponctuation preceding the "part" is when there is a leading subtitle:

- In the cloud - [part 2] the destiny => In the cloud - the destiny

So far I written a regex that "works" but I think it can be simplified.

Here is a working example:
https://regex101.com/r/0dvJL4/5 
Is there a way to simplify the repeat of the pattern (used inside the lookahead && in the regex after ?

the repeated pattern:

```
 {0,3}[\(\[]? ?[^\w]part[^\w][ -:]?(?:III|II|IV|IX|I|VIII|VII|VI|V|XIII|XII|XI|X|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|\d{1,3}){1} ?#?\.?[\)\]]?[\(\[]?(?:final)?[\)\]]?
```

thx for any advice

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would need a repeating pattern there. Also, maybe you shouldn't include *every* possible part number case (a `\w+` should do):

```
/\s*[,-]?\s*[[(]?part[\s-:]\w+#?[\])]?/ig
```

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/0dvJL4/9)

Use it with `str.replace(regex, "")` to strip out the parts you don't need.